# Failed program after creating an instance

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

Basically, I have to create a program that creates a CatManager instance and then prints out "Done!". When I did that, the program fails. I am suppose to add something to the constructor but I don't know what. My code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CatManager
{
    private ArrayList<Cat>  myCats;
    CatManager Finish = new CatManager();
    System.out.println("Done");

    public CatManager() {
        Cat cat = new Cat("Fifi", "black");
        myCats.add(cat);
        cat = new Cat("Fluffy", "spotted");
        myCats.add(cat);
        cat = new Cat("Josephine", "tabby");
        myCats.add(cat);
        cat = new Cat("Biff", "tabby");
        myCats.add(cat);
        cat = new Cat("Bumpkin", "white");
        myCats.add(cat);
        cat = new Cat("Spot", "spotted");
        myCats.add(cat);
        cat = new Cat("Lulu", "tabby");
        myCats.add(cat);
    }

    public void add(Cat aCat) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This program will fail regardless of what is in the constructor. Every instance of `CatManager` has a `CatManager` instance in it, which has a `CatManager` instance in it, which has a ... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `you didn't initialize the ArrayList`, and you have to do it before adding some objects to it. You can simply add this as first line to your constructor:

```
myCats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
```